# API Gateway Static IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I currently have an API setup within my API gateway that has a custom domain attached - https://customdomain.com/services/

I would like to know if this API would have a static IP address / range available and if so, how to get it, the reason for this is some additional security we'd like to set up on internal services.

I am not able to use the static domain name / address as an option - it has to be an IP address / range that is static?

Thank in advance

Comment: You should have a look at this, http://serverfault.com/questions/772206/how-do-i-associate-an-elasticip-to-an-api-gateway-in-aws

Comment: @thedeliciousmuffin thanks for the comment, I should have added that I had already gone through that post - although being similar, it didn't sound the same as what i was wanting - they wanting to allocation an known IP to api gateway, not use the IP of the current API gateway.

Comment: Oh, but still looks like IP for the API Gateway isn't static. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=754574&tstart=0

Comment: @thedeliciousmuffin Thanks for that link, hadn't found that one as yet - I'm hoping someone has managed to get around this :(

Comment: You can "get around" pretty much anything, but there's always going to be a tradeoff.  If you can clarify your motivation (what you're *really* trying to accomplish), perhaps a solution will become apparent.

Comment: Michael - my end goal is to lock all public facing end points and only give them access to my API gateway via ip address... I know about using certificates and header authentication,I was wondering about using the IP address rather

Comment: @Hexie I updated my answer based on your last comment. I'm not sure I would recommend the approach, but it is a possibility to consider.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to limit access *to* your API-gateway-managed services or trying to limit access to other services that API gateway needs to call?

If you're hoping to limit access to API Gateway: The IPs of all AWS-managed services are subject to change, so you can only rely on their URLs.  However, API Gateway does offer the ability to limit access to endpoints through their "API Keys" feature, which will require you to pass that key in an `x-api-key` header in your request.

One possible alternative, if you strictly need to limit based on IPs, would be to parse the IP address of the requester from the `X-Forwarded-For` header of the request that's sent to API Gateway and, if it doesn't match your allowed list, return a 403. This would not prevent you from getting charged for requests, but it would limit requesters' ability to access your data.

If you're trying to restrict access on services that your API gateway services need to call, then the [serverfault link referenced above](https://serverfault.com/questions/772206/how-do-i-associate-an-elasticip-to-an-api-gateway-in-aws) applies: Have your Lambda function execute within a VPC, which will cause public outbound traffic to have a static IP address -- namely, the gateway that your VPC subnets use.

Comment: I don't think we should use ```x-api-key``` for authentication. If you want to secure the API on API Gateway, you can use ```AWS IAM``` auth, ```Custom Auth``` or ```Cognito User Pool```. If you want to secure your backend HTTP endpoint, you can use ```Client Certificate```.

Comment: @KaHouIeong Yep - that's a BIG no,no on using API keys for authentication, and that's coming direct from AWS themselves :) 
`"API keys are not meant as a security mechanism for controlling access to an API"`

Comment: I guess I was wrong to use the term 'authentication' (edited answer accordingly), but they are certainly a way to limit access to your API.

Comment: @Hexie can you link to where that quote came from?

Comment: @falsePockets I can't remember off the top of my head but from a quick search, it looks like it was found here: `https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/60k8sc/api_gateway_authentication/` which references this `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html` I suspect AWS have moved pages around and although it's still there, it might be moved and reworded.